# Check and Uncheck checkbox based on the value in React Redux Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, redux

I am working on a React project, and have redux store configured.

Inside the redux store, there is `cuisines` array.

Each checkbox will have a value attribute with the unique cuisine id and if the checkbox is selected this value is stored in the redux store like this

```
cuisines: ["58bee38510f8981b04b379f2", "58bee38510f8981b04b37sd3]
```

Here is my component code which prints the checkboxes and at the same time it checks whether the checkbox value exists in redux store or not.

If value exist then checkbox must be selected.

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {loadJsLibraries} from './../../utils/LoadLibrary';

class Filters extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isChecked: false
    }
    cuisineStatus = (id) => {
        const cuisineFound = this.props.filters.cuisines.find((cuisineId) => {
            return cuisineId === id;
        });
        return cuisineFound ? true: false;
    }

    handleCheckBoxChange = (e) => {
        let isChecked = e.target.checked;
        alert(isChecked);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-3">
                <div id="filters_col">
                    <a 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        href="#collapseFilters" 
                        aria-expanded="true" 
                        aria-controls="collapseFilters" 
                        id="filters_col_bt
                    "> 
                    Filters 
                        <i className="icon-plus-1 pull-right"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div className="collapse" id="collapseFilters">

                        <div className="filter_type">
                            <h6>Distance</h6>
                            <input type="text" id="range" value="" name="range"/>
                            <input type="text" id="range-test" value="" />

                            <h6>Food Type</h6>
                            <ul>
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" className="icheck" />Veg Only</label></li>
                            </ul>
                            <h6>Outlet Type</h6>
                            <ul>
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" className="icheck" />Restaurant</label></li>
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" className="icheck" />Food Court</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div className="filter_type">
                            <h6>Cuisines</h6>
                            <ul className="nomargin">
                                {
                                    this.props.cuisines.map((cuisine) => {
                                        return (<li>
                                            <label className="checkbox-container">
                                                {cuisine.name}

                                                <input 
                                                    type="checkbox"
                                                    value={cuisine.id} 
                                                    className="cuisineCheckbox"
                                                    onChange={(e) => this.handleCheckBoxChange(e)}
 checked={this.cuisineStatus(cuisine.id}
                                                />
                                                <span className="checkmark"></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </li>)
                                    })
                                }
                                {loadJsLibraries()}

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(state => state)(Filters);
```

Inside the React component, there is function which will check whether the checkbox value exists in redux store or not.

If value exist in redux store, then functon returns `true` or else `false`.

This works perfectly fine, but the problem is that when I click on the checkbox, it fires the event but the check is not toggling.

**Update**
I tried this also

```
<input 
     type="checkbox"
     value={cuisine.id} 
     className="cuisineCheckbox"                                                
     onChange={(e) => this.handleCheckBoxChange(e)}
     {...(this.cuisineStatus(cuisine.id) ? {checked : true} : {})}
/>
```

But if the checkbox is checked then I am not able to uncheck it again.

Comment: Unless you setState, nothing re-renders.

Comment: You aren't dispatching any actions inside `handleCheckBoxChange`. Where do you update the Redux Store?

Comment: Check this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/9hv62Lxg/

Comment: This will answer the question:
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs

Comment: Yes, it's working now following the guide.